# How to get trained ranges for membership functions in anfis.m of matlab?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, fuzzy-logic

I need to get ranges of membership functions of inputs in an anfis in matlab. I use the following code to train my network and successfully train the network. But what I need is to get the value of ranges that the network finds for membership functions of inputs. I mean if a membership function is a bell-shaped one, like `gbellmf`, it would have this formula `(x)= exp{-((x-c)/a)^(2*b)}` and I need to know the value of `a`, `b` and `c` after the network is trained.

```
function trainedfis = main(data,chkdata)
    
fis = genfis1(data,[3 3 3],char('gbellmf','gbellmf', 'gbellmf'));
    
[trainedfis,errors,stepssize,chkfis,errchk] = anfis(data,fis,3,[1 1 1 1],chkdata);
        
end
```

also my data is a three input and one output data (3 columns for input and 1 column for output).
I use the built in `genfis1` and `anfis` of matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access all parameters of `j`-th membership function of `i`-th input by:

```
fis.input(i).mf(j).params
```

In the following example I trained fis for the Iris Data, which has 4 inputs. Then I used data stored in `fismat` to plot all membership functions:

```
close all; clc; clear variable;
%% import iris data
[x, t] = iris_dataset;
y = t(1, :)*1 + t(1, :)*2 + t(3, :)*3;
data = [x' y'];
%% train fis moddel
numMFs = [3 3 3 3];
mfType = char('gbellmf','gbellmf', 'gbellmf', 'gbellmf');
fismat = genfis1(data,numMFs,mfType);

%% plot input membership function using plotmf
subplot(2,2,1), plotmf(fismat,'input',1);
subplot(2,2,2), plotmf(fismat,'input',2);
subplot(2,2,3), plotmf(fismat,'input',3);
subplot(2,2,4), plotmf(fismat,'input',4);

%% plot input membership function manually, using fismat object
figure;
% get number of inputs
ni = numel(fismat.input);
for i=1:ni
    % get total range of all mem-funs of i-th input
    range = fismat.input(i).range; 
    subplot(2, 2, i);
    xlabel(['input ' num2str(i)]);
    xlim(range); hold on;
    x = linspace(range(1), range(2), 100);
    % get number of mem-funs of i-th input
    nmf = numel(fismat.input(i).mf);
    for j=1:nmf
        % get j-th mem-fun of i-th input
        mf = str2func(fismat.input(i).mf(j).type);
        % get parameters of j-th mem-fun of i-th input
        params = fismat.input(i).mf(j).params;
        y = mf(x, params);
        plot(x, y, 'displayname', ...
            [fismat.input(i).mf(j).type '(' num2str(params, '%.1f,') ')']);
    end
    legend('show')
end
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have a problem though. Lets say in my code, I use your manual plot algorithm once with fis, instead of your fismat, before the anfis line and once with trainedfis, instead of your fismat, after the anfis line. I get exact same shapes and ranges. Isn't it supposed to show different ranges after training? Or does the training happen in genfis1? then what does the anfis do?

Comment: @aminrahman Two different things: 1- The fis model will change after you re-train it calling `anfis`. Find the `'%.1f,'` in my code and change it to e.g. `'%.4f,'` and try again. It will increase the precision and you will see that parameters actually change. However:

Comment: 2- Parameters will probably not change much, so membership functions will look visually unchanged. This is because you are using the same data as before for retraining, it is like doubling the number of epochs. To see the effect of retraining, for example, you can first call `genfis1` with half of the data and then call `anfis` with the other half.

Comment: Yes thank you. Using your method the ranges start to change.